# Always use one space in RecycleView

Tags: android

I have a list of various devices (actually Lego trains). The list is sorted by type and name and whenever there is a new type, I would like to create a new row:

[image: Layout]

I have "solved" it with setting the span size of the item:

```
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    if (position >= devicesAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    Device deviceCurr = devicesAdapter.getDevice(position);
                    Device deviceNext = devicesAdapter.getDevice(position + 1);
                    return deviceCurr.getClass() != deviceNext.getClass() ? 2 : 1;
                }
            });
```

It actually works somehow, but the item takes now 2 columns, which makes sense and has the max width of the card.

Can I solve that somehow to enforce a new row?